# How to select one parameter from a SQL query which yields a no. of parameter?

Tags: mysql

I am having a sql query

```
select devices.id, devices.type_designator_id, devices.color, devices.status,
       devices.device_build, users.username 
from devices,users 
where 
 devices.user_id=users.id and devices.user_id=1608 
ORDER BY devices.id;
```

Now it will give me 6 output from two tables devices and users.

Now I want to extract only one output from above query (without changing the anything) type_designator_id, to put it as a parameter for next sql query with different table.

Say new table is Type_designators with a parameter name id, which is same as the type_designator_id from the previous query.

Comment: Can you try to be more specific on your problem? I mean, apparently you want that specific query, no modifications, to behave differently in order to be an input to another query, and that is not quite possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider creating a view defined by the query you've shown above, and using that view in your new query.